# Is there a way to scan through folder paths dynamically and list all files?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm testing this piece of code.

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/rawdata/2019/01/01/corp/")
```

That works fine for one folder, but if I try the line below, it fails.

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/rawdata/2019/01/*/corp/")
```

Is there a way to recursively list all files in a parent folder and all sub-folders?  I'd love to get a list of files passed into a dataframe.

I tried the code below and it works fine for loading files with similar names into a data frame.

```
val myDFCsv = spark.read.format("csv")
   .option("sep","|")
   .option("inferSchema","true")
   .option("header","false")
   .load("mnt/rawdata/2019/01/*/corp/*.gz")
```

However, I don't want to merge similar files together, I want to list file names and path names, where these files reside.  Thanks!

Comment: not sure what is that `fs` type, but you can use `globStatus` in `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`

Comment: Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the java API  `FileSystem.globStatus(Path pathPattern)`

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

val fs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
val files = fs.globStatus(new Path("/mnt/rawdata/2019/01/*/corp/"))
files.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work!!

```
import sys, os
import pandas as pd

mylist = []
root = "/dbfs/mnt/rawdata/"
path = os.path.join(root, "targetdirectory")
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
  for name in files:
    mylist.append(os.path.join(path, name))

len(mylist)
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
```